# Where to keep display information in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I was wondering where the best place was to keep display output information in Struts2.

So I have a class that has variable rows, and columns of data. Now currently I am calling `toString` to output the information in a table format. I understand how that can be incorrect because if I wanted to later change the table format I would have to reconfigure the java file.  The problem is that it would be extremely hard for me to go through all the arraylists and create a properly formatted table in pure struts 2 though.

So my question is: Is it ever OK to just have the output* be created through toString? or should I try to figure out a way to do it all in struts2 only?

*By output I mean a small section of the website such as an html table.

Answer (score 0):

Imho it is *totally* wrong; it is an *outdated* strategy from the ancient times of the Servlets, in the pre-JSP era, where you were forced to print out HTML from Java Strings through the ServletOutputStream...

Since a table can have:

- Rows

  - draw odd and even rows of different colors, to help the user's eye;
  - highlighting on mouseover of the current row
  - select on click of the row
- Pagination

  - Indicators: "page 1 of 2"
  - Navigation buttons: `<< First < Prev | Next > Last >>`
  - Server side configurable *Step Size*: read from DB or Properties file how much elements to show per-page
  - Direct page selector through an SelectBox
  - Search functionality
- Graphic:

  - all managed through CSS

and you can have simple tables with only some of that features, and complex tables with all of that, you could create modules / configurable objects for each characteristic, so that when you need a table you simply configure which modules you want and your code, tested and ready, is already there.

With a table generated from a `toString()`, for each new table you will need to do the work again, or even worst to *copy-paste-drop* ; the same is applied to each modify to an existent table;

this is an horrible, unmaintainable bunch of static code that you don't want to leave to your coworkers in the future.

Start with basic, then add one brick at a time.

You can use [DisplayTag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/) at first, it has most built in features that may help reaching the goal fast.

Then you could draw your own objects, keeping in mind that the graphics should always be handled through CSS, the HTML structure should not be handled in Java (you could use, for example, multiple JSP snippets, mounted together with `<jsp:include />`).

Finally, you could draw your own object through taglibraries... then most of the html code would be generated by Java, but in the "right" way.

If you need AJAX functionalities, you can take a look at Struts2-jQuery-Grid Plugin too: 
http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag